# Custom Input Names on GravityForms

Tags: html, forms, wordpress, input, gravity

How can I add custom input names to gravity forms? I need to submit a form to a third party service that requires very specific form names.

My current idea is to write a bit of jQuery to dynamically rename everything when the page loads. Obviously this isn't ideal.

Gravity Forms: http://www.gravityforms.com/

Comment: GF has a bunch of action and filter hooks, have you checked those?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After contacting the makers of Gravity Forms, it sounds like they don't support custom input names. As a workaround, I wrote a bit of jQuery to rename inputs with the correct form names. For example:

```
$("input#input_1_1").attr("name","first_name");
```

Answer (score 0):

Just put some code in functions.php and fill out the form which will then email you with a list of the id names, they are the same names that you can fine using developer tools etc. This was just faster for me. Then change the code to have it post via curl with different input names.

This uses php so it's on the server to handle. That way you don't have to worry about people with JS disabled in their browser.

http://0to5.com/gravity-forms-submitting-forms-to-3rd-party-applications/

Comment: This no longer works. Throws an error on the latest version of Gforms + WP.

Comment: I'll have to test again and see if it still works for me, thank for the update!

Answer (score 0):

Add a new field (HTML field). In content settings of this field add this javascript with script tags

Non-jquery solution:

```js
document.getElementById("input_14_4").setAttribute("name", "email");
```

Another solution i found here

https://docs.gravityforms.com/gform_field_content/

```
add_filter( 'gform_field_content', function ( $field_content, $field , $value, $lead_id, $form_id) {
 if ( $form['id'] != 14 ) {
        //not the form whose tag you want to change, return the unchanged tag
        return $field_content;
    }
    if ( $field->id == 3 ) {
        return  preg_replace( "|name='(.*?)'|", "name='email'", $field_content );
    }
  
    return $field_content;
}, 10, 5 );
```

Comment: Code-only answers are not particularly helpful. Please add some descriptions of how this code solves the problem.